# valueChangeListener clearing value on submit and not invoking the related listener

Tags: jsf, valuechangelistener

Regards.

I have an simple application developed with following facets

- JSF 1.2
- Dynamic Web Module 2.5
- Java 5
- RichFaces 3.3.2

My Jsf page code snippet is as follows:-

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="x"%>
   ...
  <h:selectOneMenu styleClass="combo" id="Country"
  onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{countryBean.countryChanged}">
      <f:selectItems value="#  {countryBean.countryList}"/>
   </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Related backing bean code snippet :-

```
public void countryChanged(javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("...........Country Changed.........." + event.getNewValue());   

}
```

I have 2 problems that need to be looked into.

- Firstly, the value in the combo box is vanished when i select any value
- Secondly, nothing is printed from with in the countryChange method, which means, obviously that my valueChangeListener is not being invoked.

Plz let me know what possibly could i be missing here.

Comment: Did you surround this combobox with a <h:form> tag?

Comment: Yes sir. it is inside <h:form>

Comment: Used a4j:support and job was well done. Thanks All.